# Plus one in calculating area of rectangle

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, non-maximum-suppression

```
areas = (end_x - start_x + 1) * (end_y - start_y + 1)
```

Above is what use in calculating area of rectangle for non-max-suppression in two different links below, why there is a need for plus one?

https://github.com/amusi/Non-Maximum-Suppression/blob/master/nms.py
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/

Comment: This seems to have been asked [in a comment](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/#article-comment-367649) but I'm not sure if the answer makes any sense as I don't know the context.

Comment: Do you mean the intersection area?

Comment: Could be Laplace smoothing.

Comment: I think this is so the area of a single pixel is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that plus one is just used to get the exact area.
For example,
width begin in pixel 2, end in pixel 4. The exact width is 3 (pixel 2, 3, 4).
A 3 equals to 4 - 2 + 1.

But in my opion, it's not essential to care about that. Just make sure you cal every area in the same standard.